# JUnit not calling object equals when testing

Tags: java, junit

JUnit is throwing this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<com.mycompany.models.EntityStringProperty@1e81f4dc> but was:<com.mycompany.models.EntityStringProperty@4d591d15>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.mycompany.models.EntityPropertyTest.testStringEntity(EntityPropertyTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

For this test:

```java
  @Test
  public void testStringEntity() {
    EntityProperty stringProperty = new EntityStringProperty("hello world");
    EntityProperty stringPropertyCompare = new EntityStringProperty("hello world");
    assertEquals(stringProperty, stringPropertyCompare);
  }
```

Even the `equals` had been overridden:

```java
public class EntityStringProperty extends PrimitiveEntityProperty { 
  /* NOTE: PrimitiveEntityProperty implements EntityProperty */
  public EntityStringProperty(String stringValue) {
    super(stringValue, String.class);
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (EntityStringProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
      EntityStringProperty property = (EntityStringProperty) obj;
      if (getStringValue().equals(property.getStringValue()) && getValueType().isAssignableFrom(
          property.getClass())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**What could be wrong here?** How can I make this test for the equals for the two object correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman I can see that code shows a  *minimal reproducible example*, check the `testStringEntity` method.

Comment: @quarks What is the implementation of `getValueType()`?

Comment: Do you meant to use `property.getValueType()` instead of `property.getClass()`? My guess it that `getValueType()` is returning the class used in the `super()` call, which will be `String.class`, but `property.getClass()` will be the `EntityStringProperty` class. So `String != EntityStringProperty`.

Comment: @Progman is it solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to fix this, change the implemenation of `equals` to this:

```java
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (EntityStringProperty.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
      EntityStringProperty property = (EntityStringProperty) obj;
      if (getStringValue().equals(property.getStringValue()) && getValueType().isAssignableFrom(
          property.getValueType())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Notice the change,

`getValueType().isAssignableFrom(property.getValueType())`